# Visual Studio Search Filter?

Tags: visual-studio

Visual Studio:

Quite often, I search for say "`max-`" in "Current Project" and I have to spend time hitting the "`->`" (next button) whilst it informs me of all of the `jQuery/knockout/bootstrap`. files that contain this string.  None of which I am interested in.  I'm only interested in my code (for example).

Does anyone know of a way (may be through an add-in), that you can mark files/folders in a Solution with "`Do not Search`"?

Filtering by file type (eg "`.cshtml`") is not sufficient.

I am aware of a workaround using "`Find All`", that makes it easier to pick the ones you want.  However, even that option would benefit from a filter.

Thanks Rob

Answer (score 1):

There is an button after the Look in option dropdown, marked with [...], in the dialogue that pops up, you can select the folders that you want to search in.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  That is with "Find In Files" from the Edit Menu.  It only goes down the folder level, which could be good enough, it's just that I would have though it would be easier to select were you "DON'T" want to search...

Comment: Ièm not sure I understand "only goes down the folder level", I can select any folder/drive that I want to search in, but yes an exclude would have been nice as well.